# AES 256 Encryption is not matching with result

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I have a document that is saying to Encrypted string `using AES256`. According to my document with two value `10002:1486703720424 AND  HashKey: hpIw4SgN)TxJdoQj=GKo)p83$uHePgoF` it will generate the result `1ltQFLRGNif73uCNzi0YEvBqLKiRgx6fWsk5e/GcTQc=` but when i try to generate the result it is generating `6SKbqJAxbBrg4eU7r/B8gJoJEPg+KjMvGL5L7bfykUU=` from my code. Can you please tell what i am doing mistakes. This is the first time when i doing encryption so i am little bit confuse to find the my mistakes.

```
string getHashKey1 = EncryptText("10002:1486703720424", "hpIw4SgN)TxJdoQj=GKo)p83$uHePgoF");

public string EncryptText(string input, string password)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        // Get the bytes of the string
        byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        // Hash the password with SHA256
        passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

        byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

        result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog errLog = new ErrorLog();
        errLog.LogsWrite(ex, Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));

    }

    return result;
}

public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
    try
    {
        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 23, 234, 37, 48, 134, 63, 248, 4 };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);  
                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog errLog = new ErrorLog();
        errLog.LogsWrite(ex, Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));
    }    

    return encryptedBytes;
}
```

Comment: Are all the extra operations you are doing part of the specification too or have you just copied and pasted random code off the internet and expected it to work?  I feel like it might be the latter...  What block mode does the document specify?  What is the IV if needed?  Way more information is required!

Comment: @LukePark just i use the https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt article to use AES 256 encryption. Because in my development document says only that Encrypted string using AES256  with clientid and hashkey that i put in my function to generate the key

Comment: "AES 256" could refer to hundreds, even thousands, of potential setups.  What block mode?  CBC, ECB, CTR?  Or is it authenticated?  GCM, EAX?  What is the IV?  There are literally `2^128` different options for an IV.  What padding is used?  There are at least 3 common padding modes.  See what I mean?  You need more information, you can't just copy and paste code for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found... They are using ECB as the cypher mode, so no IV. I won't comment on the "security" of this. The padding seems to be PKCS7 (the default of AES). The password is used "as is", simply encoded in UTF8 (or perhaps even ASCII) (so it must be 32 bytes long).

```
public static string EncryptText(string input, string password)
{
    // Get the bytes of the string
    byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

    byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

    string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
    return result;
}

public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = passwordBytes;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            // "zero" IV
            aes.IV = new byte[16];

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
        }

        byte[] encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        return encryptedBytes;
    }
}
```

@LukePark correctly made a tirade about this answer that is useful for the OP but useless in the greater world. I'll bold the **correctly** word. For this reason I'll explain what is "wrong" on the specification given to A. Goutam and what a "correct" specification must always contain.

A specification for encryption should always contain: the algorithm used (AES for example), the key size (if you say AES256 then clearly it is 256 bits), the block mode (CBC, ECB etc). Many block modes (CBC for example) require an IV vector. ECB has a lower security than other block modes (see for example https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-i-use-ecb-or-cbc-encryption-mode-for-my-block-cipher). If the IV is necessary, then the specification must contain it (or explain how it should be generated). The specification must contain the padding that should be used. The `Padding.None` should be used only if the data to be encrypted can be exactly subdivided in encryption blocks (so for example, with AES, `PaddingMode.None` is good only if the data is 16, 32, 64, 96, ... bytes). `PaddingMode.Zeros` is good only for text (and I wouldn't use it, because it will add `'\0'` at the end of the text). The other padding modes are good.

Often the key isn't used "as is", because for example it is a string. The specification should contain how the encryption key must be derived from the string key. `SHA256` on the key is a weak solution. Normally a good solution is using a strong key derivation function, like `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. If this function is used, the specification must contain the number of iteration and other informations about using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` or similar functions. Clearly what encoding should be used for the key (and for the data to be encrypted, if it is a text) must be included (`UTF8` is always a good idea).

I'll add that a good specification should contain some test cases. At least one test case should be of length smaller than the encryption block and at least one test case **must** be of length greater than the encryption block but smaller than two encryption blocks (or > 2 and < 3... some complete blocks and one non-complete block). In this way you are testing both the `PaddingMode` and the `CipherMode` (note the should/must: by testing something bigger than an encryption block plus an incomplete block you are already testing everything)

Comment: you are awesome . Thanks this works for me . Upvoating your answer

Comment: Another OP that learnt literally nothing since he would have just copied and pasted... You shouldn't post code to answer these questions, it just promotes bad security practices.

Comment: @LukePark In this particular case, while the OP didn't learn anything, he wasn't creating a specification, he was using the specification of someone else, so the bad security practice was already "in place". But I too think that they are doing bad security practice.

Comment: It's more the fact that, by not providing the code, the OP would have actually gone and *learnt* how to modify his code to fit.  Which means the OP would know more about encryption and cryptography.  Which means when the OP implements something of his own in the future, it might only be half as bad as it is going to be without that knowledge.  See what I mean?

Comment: Not to mention that the whole point of SO is for people to learn.

Comment: @LukePark I too think that persons should learn by themselves, but this isn't "that" type of forum. If someone wants to learn by himself, then he rarely will need to write questions on SO, because what you can't find on google is normally something very esoteric that few persons have tried (and few know). This is a Q/A site for persons that want a solution "now"... In a perfect world persons would self-learn, self-exercise and self-research. In a perfect world :-)

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what StackOverflow is for, but lets agree to disagree.  :)

Comment: @LukePark I've added a "FYI" part to the reply... So now the answer is good even for other persons that will stumble upon it.